# HL7 V3 ITS R2 - Person Name

Tags: hl7

Hello fellow HL7 developers,

a question regarding the XML representation of person/patient names came up while I browsed the most recent normative release of the HL7 standard (release 2014). This version of the standard uses ITS R2 (new schemas, changed datatypes).

According to the standard (CD1/Edition2014/infrastructure/itsxml/datatypes_its_xml.html, section 2.20.2), a person name should be represented by XML elements "<given>", "<family>" etc. However, no such elements are defined anywhere in the XSD files that accompany the standard. How is a person name correctly rendered in XML in this version of the standard?

Regards,
Michael

Answer (score 1):

datatypes_its_xml.html is the filename of the R1 version of the specification. Although you are looking at an R2 based version, R1 is included for information sake, and you've found it. Use ISO data types 21090 which is the correct version for the schema.

As for names, in this version  if my memory is correct.